# Multiple domains and one session fat-free framework

Tags: php, session, fat-free-framework

is there any way to handle the same session with multiple domains | subdomains? Everything is on the same server. I know there are solutions for subdomains in pure PHP like ini_set('session.cookie_domain',[]); etc. but F3 framework saves session's data in cache directory that i specify. I will be very gratefull for positive answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes the idea to set the session cookie domain is already right.
Try to set that with:

```
$f3->set('JAR.domain','*.mydomain.com');
```

clear your site cookies and try again. That should make your cookie available for all sub-domains too.

Comment: For me `*.mydomain.com` not works. Works: `.mydomain.com`